# NumPy - Sum of the elements on the secondary diagnoal of a 2D matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, diagonal

How can I get the sum of the elements on the secondary diagonal of a matrix? `numpy.trace` seems to only return main diagonals, and `numpy.diagonal` doesn't seem to help out with secondary diagonal either.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could always just flip the array `a` (top to bottom) and use `np.trace`:

```
a[::-1].trace()
```

Comment: I guess this'll do. Thanks (will accept when SO allows)

Comment: @confused00 - no problem. I don't know of any NumPy functions that calculate the secondary diagonal explicitly, but this method should be relatively efficient.

Comment: You are actually flipping it top to bottom, not left to right, but it does the job just the same.